# linux shell bug : noclobber option

Tags: linux, bash, shell

On Linux, running the command below will force the terminal to shut down.
While using the noclobber option, I accidentally gave the -e option instead of the -o option and ran it.
There seems to be a bug in the Linux shell.

```
yuko@hpc:~$ set -e noclobber
yuko@hpc:~$ ps > ps.txt
yuko@hpc:~$ ps > ps.txt
yuko@hpc:~$ set -o noclobber
yuko@hpc:~$ ps > ps.txt
-bash: ps.txt: cannot overwrite existing file
Connection closing...Socket close.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: Do you know what `set -e` does? Why do you think it's a bug? Did you read any documentation that would document a different bash behavior in this case?

Comment: my mistake. ^^ ;;

Answer (score 1):

No bug.

From the manual:

```
-e
Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a single
simple command (see Simple Commands), a list (see Lists), or a compound 
command (see Compound Commands) returns a non-zero status.
```

You did a set -e, requesting it to exit when there is an error. Then, with the `noclobber` you created an error. And therefore the shell exits.

Comment: thank you for your reply. What you gave me was very helpful.